# Let $f:\Bbb D \rightarrow \Bbb H$ be holomorphic with $f(0)=i$, show the following inequality holds

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f:\Bbb D \rightarrow \Bbb H$ be holomorphic with $f(0)=i$, show the following inequality holds:

$\frac{1-|z|}{1+|z|} \leq |f(z)| \leq \frac{1+|z|}{1-|z|}$

and that $|f'(0)|\leq 2$

This looks sort of like a Schwarz ineqality.

Let $g: \Bbb H \rightarrow \Bbb D$ be the conformal map

$g(z) = \frac{i-z}{i+z}$. Then $h=g\circ f$ is a map from the disc to itself with $f(0)=0$, so the Schwarz lemma gives

$|\frac{i-f(z)}{i+f(z)}| \leq |z|$

but I do not see how to proceed.

Comment: Idea: Square both sides of your last inequality and 'solve for $f(z) $'.

Comment: @Jose27 This doesn't seem to work. Do you have any other suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $h$ be the composed map as in your statement.

We know that $$|\dfrac{i-f(z)}{i+f(z)}| \leq |z|,$$ thus , $$|i-f(z)| \leq |z| |i+f(z)| \leq |z|+|z||f(z)|.$$  By the triangle inequality, we know that

$$|f(z)| \leq |z| +|z| |f(z)| +1.$$Rearrange, and we get that $$|f(z)|-|z||f(z)| \leq |z|+1,$$ and by dividing by $1-|z|$ we get $$|f(z)|\leq \dfrac{|z|+1}{|1-|z|}.$$

The other inequality is straightforward and follows by a similar strategy. Can you work this out or do you want me to write down the answer to that as well?